# WSL2 creates local listener for remote port for SSH remote tunnel

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-tunnel

I currently try to create an SSH tunnel between my Windows system and a WSL2 instance running on it. My goal is to have a Burp Proxy running on Windows that I can access from both Windows itself as well as from inside the WSL.

Ideally, this tunnel should be established on the startup of Windows so it can be used at any time. Furthermore, the ports on both systems should be the same so that scripts containing explicit values for the proxy work in both environments.

For this, I started an sshd in the WSL instance and create a remote tunnel from my Windows:

```
Start-Process ssh -ArgumentList "-i C:\Users\frank.ssh\id_ed25519 frank@172.29.157.41 -R8080:127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Now, in theory, I can reach the Burp Proxy by connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080 on both Windows and WSL.

When testing, I encountered behaviour that I could not explain. If Burp Proxy is already running when I start the tunnel, everything works as expected. If the tunnel was created first, the Proxy failed to start as the port was already in use.

After playing a bit, I noticed that my local Windows (via wslhost) will always attempt to create a local listener on the same port used for the remote side. If this fails, e.g. because there is already a listener, nothing bad is apparent.

In the first try Burp Proxy had already created the listener before the tunnel was established:

```
LocalAddress  : 127.0.0.1
LocalPort     : 8080
RemoteAddress : 0.0.0.0
RemotePort    : 0
State         : Listen
Process       : BurpSuitePro
```

However, when I tried again without Burp Proxy running, wslhost opened a listener:

```
LocalAddress  : 127.0.0.1
LocalPort     : 8080
RemoteAddress : 0.0.0.0
RemotePort    : 0
State         : Listen
Process       : wslhost
```

The linux side is identical in both cases and as expected:

```
→ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1003/sshd: frank@pt
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      254/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      359/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8080                :::*                    LISTEN      1003/sshd: frank@pt
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      359/sshd: /usr/sbin
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           254/systemd-resolve
```

To see whether wslhost uses the port values of the local or remote side, I tried using different port numbers:

```
-R5555:127.0.0.1:7777
```

Here, the linux side opens a listener on 5555 (expected)

```
→ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1438/sshd: frank@pt
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      254/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      359/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5555                :::*                    LISTEN      1438/sshd: frank@pt
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      359/sshd: /usr/sbin
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           254/systemd-resolve
```

but the windows side also open the wslhost listener on port 5555 if it is available (unexpected):

```
LocalAddress  : 127.0.0.1
LocalPort     : 5555
RemoteAddress : 0.0.0.0
RemotePort    : 0
State         : Listen
Process       : wslhost
```

Is there a way to prevent wslhost to create a local listener for the remote port? While manually creating the tunnel after I start Burp Proxy is a workaround, I'd like to automatically establish the tunnel on startup.

And why it is created in the first place?

My environment:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1766]
  NAME          STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu        Running         2
Kernel version: 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
```

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here.  I noticed, but forgot to mention, that it would be great if you would paste the text output as text, rather than as images.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for why.  From the WSL side, you can capture it with something like `sudo netstat -tulpn 2>&1 | tee >(clip.exe)`.  PowerShell can, of course, pipe to `clip.exe` as well.  I'm still working on groking the full question, but I'm not quite there yet.

Comment: Probably won't matter, but (just in case) what distribution are you using in WSL?  Can you provide the output from `wsl -l -v` (from PowerShell) in an edit?  I haven't tested this on my end, but the behavior you are seeing would be expected if the distribution was running as WSL1.  The fact that the default version in your `--status` is showing as 2 doesn't mean that the instance itself isn't version 1.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Done, thanks for the advice.